# htaccess rewriting url

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How would i have to change the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?administration=$1&pid=$2 [L]
```

To affect not only an url like

```
www.example.com/administration/modules //this is working allready
```

But also an url like f.e.

```
www.example.com/upload/category
```

Or just

```
www.example.com/news
```

Thanx in Advance, Jayden

Comment: For `/administration/modules` target URI is `/index.php?administration=administration&pid=modules` likewise what should be target URI for `/upload/category` and `/news`?

Comment: for /upload/category it would be /index.php?upload=upload&pid=category, for /news it would be /index.php?pid=news

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?$1=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: hi anubhava and thanks for your reply. why would i need to use httpd.conf in this example? im asking, because i dont know this kind of file and most approaches for url-rewriting i saw online didnt mention it.

Comment: You don't need to edit httpd.conf if you already have `mod_rewrite and .htaccess` enabled.

Comment: ok, thanx. but by using the lines you posted, i get 500 server error

Comment: Ah ok, I edited my answer to take care of that. Please check it now.

Comment: thanx alot anubhava, this seems to be working. only thing now is, it seems that the urls are being cached. is there any way i can prevent that?

Comment: ok, sry, this was a browser-cache thing. deleted browser cache, now it works... thanks again, jayden

Comment: yes, it really works like a charme. Now there is a little change, i would like to implement for performance-reasons. AtM the used get-param for the php is a string (fe value of pid = modules) and the db has to check varchar-fields. I would like to change the htaccess so it can handle links like "/modules_55" where 55 would be the id from the record 'modules' and htaccess would direct to the url 'index.php?pid=55'. Can htaccess do that, like extracting the part after the '_'? also, removing the  '_55' from the visible url, should this be done by htaccess or better per header within php?

Comment: @jayden: That is actually a little different problem than this question. I request you to post that as a separate question here on SO and I will certainly try to answer it.